# Do you need to use phpmyadmin to import excel data to mysql - im struggling to install phpadmin? Are there alternative ways?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, tornado, gcloud

I wanted to copy the data from excel spreadsheet to MySQL. This data will imported to gcloud app engine, I have already deployed a live website - this is where the data will be visible. I am  using the framework tornado. At the moment I am struggling to import the data to MySQL.

I watched a few youTube videos- they all seem to be using myphpadmin.I am confused as I don't know what my local host is?

Comment: Export Excel sheets to .csv files and then use [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/to/some.csv' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Answer (score 0):

With phpMyAdmin, you can import the .csv file that was exported from Excel. Open your table, then Import and choose the CSV format.